# How do I return two columns from first table if only one column partially matches with the second one?

Tags: sql-server-2008, join, outer-join

```
select art.artno, art.name  from Art 
left outer join store on art.artno =store.artno  
where art.Artno not in (select art.artno from store)
```

The query is supposed to be like this but seems not working(I do not get any result rows beside the column names). Using a MSSQL 2008.

```
table art             table store                 EXPECTED RESULT 
artno   name          artno qty                  artno   name 
    1    xbox360          1   1                      2     XHW
    2    XHW              3   2                      5     PS2
    3    NETANDO          4   1
    5    PS2              6   3
    6    PS1 
    4    X1
```

How do I write a query to get the Expected out shown in the example?

Just to let you know the tables are 100plus K rows large if helps.

Finally some lights on why the above code does not work would be beneficial. I looked at this [this link](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) seems that outer join must work, may be I could not understand this at all.

I tried with `full outer join` as well, did not help. Using `except` I was able to find just the `artno` but did not let me produce the `name` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another approach could be

```
select
  a.`artno`,
  a.`name`
from
  art a
left join
  store s on s.artno=a.artno
where
  s.artno is null
```

On large tables, the second approach would most likely be better.

Comment: @tuncay , Thanks. The second option helped but not the first one, I cannot explain why, but if you do it would be helpful.

Comment: Would you please let me know if the position of the `s.artno` and `s.artno` after on are related to `left` and `right` of of the `join` statement.

Comment: I dont really think so. Its a condition and I specified explicit table aliases ("a" and "s").

Comment: In the statement `left join store on store.artno=art.artno` if I change the position like `left join store on art.artno=store.artno` what option should I use with the `join`(`left join`or `right join`)? just to know, the problem is solved already just wanted to know ...

Comment: I dont think the direction of the condition has any effect on the selected join type. so you could use `a.artno=s.artno` or `s.artno=a.artno` with same left join (or right join)

Answer (score 0):

```
select art.artno, art.name from art
where art.artno not in (select store.artno from store)
```

You don't need to do any kind of join to use an inner query (the `(select store.artno from store)` in this case). The inner query is like building a temporary table, filling it with values, and using it in the query.

Since you want your inner query to give you all `artno` in the table `store`, you should use `(select store.artno from store)` and not `(select art.artno from store)`, since I think that would select the `art.artno` from the outer query, without taking into account the contents of the `store` table.

Comment: This seems not working I have tried it as well. But don´t know why? Seems must be joined to get the result like that.

Comment: This works fine with sqlite3. I can't test with MSSQL since I don't have it, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Georges answer works, but on tables of that size a correlated subquery with a 'not exists' will be quicker.

Tested, my subqueries were slower than left outer. It's the way forward

Comment: @Tuncay and Gene : Yes, but it depends a lot on the work done by the optimizer. For example, if you have an index on store.artno and another on art.artno, then I think the sqlite engine will behave with an inner query as fast as if you had made a join.

Comment: as tables get larger, subqueries will invariably get slower, when compared to joins. I usually try to avoid subqueries where I can. Lesson thaught by MySQL version<4.

Comment: @gene, Thanks, This would take large query time, so I tried it and took more than a min and stopped it. Sorry I had to edit the query I initially presented to match the given example.